# Unable to update/write values in OPCUA Simulated Server using FIWARE

Tags: curl, fiware, fiware-orion, opc-ua

I am trying to do two communication to read and write values from OPCUA Simulated Server using FIWARE. I am successful in reading the values from the server.

[image: Screenshot (48)]
.
However, I am still facing issues in updating/writing the values. I am using this to update the value.

```
`{   
    "actionType": "update",
    "entities": [
        
        {
         "id": "age01_7:Simulation",
         "type": "3:Simulation",
         "3:test2": {
            "type": "Number",
            "value": "44",
            "metadata": {}
            
         }
        }
        ]
}`
```

It is working with **http://localhost:1026/v2/op/update** but it only updates the value within the container, not in the Server.

[image]
[image]

Also, when I try to update using this **http://localhost:4001/v2/op/update** it gives me this error after several minutes

[image: Screenshot (49)]

Comment: Which service is listening at port 4001?